# Azure Load Balancer forwarding request to vm

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-load-balancer

We have a Azure internal load balancer forwarding request to backend VM'S.

Is there a way to find out how many requests are server by each VM ? In other words how many requests are forwarded to each VM from the load balancer.

Comment: i dont think so, internal lb dont even have proper metrics as far as I remember

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could adopt [Standard Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-overview#why-use-standard-load-balancer). You will see some differences between Standard Load Balancer and Basic Load Balancer in that linking document. For internal standard LB, you can check [the SYN (synchronize) packets metric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-diagnostics#multi-dimensional-metrics) which collecting flows and their handshakes are always between the source and the VM instance.

[image]

For other scenarios, you could collect the network trace by networking capturing tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).